# Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'borderWidth' in Android Studio

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, android-appcompat

First of all I would like to clarify that a lot about this has been written, I've read some posts but the common things they say I have them done. Download the latest Support Library version, Support repository version, etc. Also I'm compiling against the latest available SDK version. My problem is when adding styles for the Floating Action Button and when adding for example app:layout_behavior for the RecyclerView. That causes me the same kind of problems. Actually I'm trying to introduce the Material design in an older app. With the new ones I have no problems, but I've checked and the configuration is the same. Am I missing something?

Here is my current configuration.

[image]

Module build.grade:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}
```

Top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here are the styles causing me problems with borderWidth, pressedTranslationZ and rippleColor:

```
<style name="FabStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/fab_compat_margin</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_add</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">6dp</item>
    <item name="pressedTranslationZ">12dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Here is my layout. If I remove the Floating Action Button along with its styles, then the problem is with the layout_behaviour of the RecyclerView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.egane.BaseCustomersActivityActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                style="@style/FabStyle"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'` as a dependency?

Comment: Of course, I updated the build.gradle file reflecting my dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html), the Floating action button belongs to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton which means you should add

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23+'`